# Why does the return value -1 become 4294967295 when return type is int64_t？

Tags: c

In this code, I have a function whose return value is `-1`, but when assigned to `int64_t` type, the value obtained is `4294967295` instead of `-1`, but when assigned to `int32_t` type, it is `-1`. The return value of that `zip_name_locate` is of type `int` (4 bytes on my system). why is that?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zip.h>

int main() {
    const char * path = "/home/www/api/default/current/public/static/doc/test.xlsx";

    int error = ZIP_ER_NOENT;
    zip_t* zip = zip_open(path, ZIP_RDONLY, &error);

    int32_t n = zip_name_locate(zip, "xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.rels", ZIP_FL_NODIR);
    printf("%d\n", n);

    int64_t j = zip_name_locate(zip, "xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.rels", ZIP_FL_NODIR);
    printf("%" PRId64 "\n", j);

    return 0;
}
```

output：

```
-1
4294967295
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Can you come up with an example that doesn't use the "zip" functions?

Comment: The function `zip_name_locate` appears to come from [libzip](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_name_locate.html)

Comment: The return type does not change because you assign it to a different type. The return type is `int`, assigning it to `int64_t` is an implicit cast. not a change of return type.  The size of `int` differs between platforms, I guess this is either a 32-bit platform or Windows?

Comment: OP may not have a good understanding of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: @chux: it seems that `zip_name_locate` returns a `zip_int64_t`, which is typedef'd as `int64_t` in zipconf.h. So this shouldn't be a case of assigning a signed value to an unsigned type. Tough to tell if it's a case of incorrect code being emitted or of `PRId64` being incorrectly defined by whatever compiler OP is using, but those would be my initial suspicions.

Comment: @Joe An implicit cast of a signed type to a larger signed type should not change the sign or magnitude however.

Comment: You are relying on the implementation of `printf()` to correctly display the value of an `int64_t`; that is unreliable in my experience.  Observe the value of `j` in your debugger - that will tell you its true value.

Comment: How old is your libzip? `zip_name_locate`'s return type changed in 0.11, released March 23, 2013. The current version is 1.7.3.

Comment: Following up on the comment from @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, what is the output of `printf("%s\n", PRId64);` on your compiler/architecture?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long));`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, if that is the case, then I suspect there is a mismatch  between header file and library versions.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and tell your OS type and version, the version of `libzip` and how you installed the library. Can you reproduce the problem with `int64_t j = -1;` or `int64_t j = (int64_t)((zip_int64_t)-1);`?

Comment: The behaviour of the code indicates that the function is actually returning the value `4294967295`

Comment: Rolled back -- please do not post Answers as edits to the Question. Instead post the answer in the Answer box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my system information:

```
➜  ~ uname -r
3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
➜  ~ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
➜  ~ gcc --version                           
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks for answering, here are some answers to your questions：

- About `libzip`, Because this is related to a bug I encountered in the process, so I need to use zip
- My system is 64bit CentOS 7.7
- `zip_name_locate` does return `zip_int64_t` type
- I printed n and `j` in gdb, `n` is `-1`, `j` is `4196160`, it seems that gdb cannot print integers of type `int64_t`, but this output indicates that `j` should not be `-1`
- Because we used an old version of `libzip` in a certain environment and caused a bug, so we wanted to find the most fundamental reason, we used the built-in version `0.11`
- `PRId64` is `ld` on my system
- `int64_t j = -1;` and `int64_t j = (int64_t)((zip_int64_t)-1);`  successful conversion
- `sizeof(long)` is 8

I made a mistake. On my system, I have an old version of `libzip` and a new version of `libzip`, but when I tried to introduce the old version of `libzip` with the `-L` flag, the new version was actually introduced. The method I compiled is
`gcc -L /usr/lib64 -lzip test1.c -o test` and `/usr/lib64` is where the old version of `libzip` dynamic shared library is located.

In my system, there are some `libzip` library files under `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/local/lib64`, the old version under `/usr/lib64`, and the new version under `/usr/local/lib64`:

```
ls -lh /usr/local/lib64/libzip.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Jun  1 22:21 /usr/local/lib64/libzip.so -> libzip.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Jun  1 22:21 /usr/local/lib64/libzip.so.5 -> libzip.so.5.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 162K Jun  1 23:18 /usr/local/lib64/libzip.so.5.3

ls -lh /usr/lib64/libzip.so* 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 57K Jun  2 00:02 /usr/lib64/libzip.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11 Jun  2 00:07 /usr/lib64/libzip.so.2 -> libzip.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 57K Jun  2 00:02 /usr/lib64/libzip.so.2.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 57K Jun  2 00:02 /usr/lib64/libzip.so.5
```

I learned that the `objdump` command can check which shared libraries are dependent, so I checked it out and the following is the output:

```
objdump -p test | grep so                 
  NEEDED               libzip.so.2
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  required from libc.so.6:
```

Then I checked through ldconfig and found that `libzip.so.2` points to the new version:

```
ldconfig -v | grep libzip
    libzip.so.5 -> libzip.so.5.3
    libzip.so.2 -> libzip.so.5
```

So in my question, it was based on a wrong judgment from the beginning, leading to incomprehensible imagination. If you are using a new version of `libzip`, the return value of `zip_name_locate` of `libzip` in the new version is `zip_int64_t`. This type is `int64_t` type on my system. When the `4294967295` return value of this type is assigned to `int32_t`, it causes overflow, so would be `-1`, and j would be `4294967295`.

Comment: there's no reason gdb can't print `int64_t`

Comment: If you want to link a certain library, put it **after** the module referencing it. You want `gcc -L /usr/lib64 test1.c -lzip -o test`.

Comment: @phuclv Yes, this is also a wrong judgment, I can print `int64_t`